# Thread safe read from a std::vector of std::tuple of double?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, thread-safety, stdvector

Consider a class containing the following vector:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<double, double, double> > _data;
```

and the following member function:

```
inline double second(const unsigned int i) const
{
    return std::get<1>(_data[i]);
}
```

Do I have the guarantee that this function is thread-safe (note that I return a copy of the double)?

If not, what would be a thread-safe version of this function?

Comment: it is thread safe as long as you don't write to _data[i]

Comment: If your vector can be modified by another thread, this isn't safe without some sort of synchronization.

Comment: @yngum I think you meant, `_data`, not `_data[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not thread-safe if the `std::vector` can be modified by another thread. To make it thread-safe, access to the `std::vector` must be synchronized. A possible solution is to introduce a [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) and associate it with the `std::vector` instance. In this case, the `std::mutex` would be a member variable of the class that contains the `std::vector`:

```
#include <mutex>

class X
{
private:
    std::vector<std::tuple<double, double, double>> data_;
    mutable std::mutex data_mutex_;
public:
    double second(const unsigned int i) const
    {
        // Note that 'operator[]' is not bounds checked.
        // Recommend adding a check to ensure 'i' is
        // within range or use 'at()'.

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(data_mutex_);
        return std::get<1>(data_[i]);
    }
};
```

Note the addition of the `std::mutex` makes the class non-copyable as it itself is non-copyable.

Comment: Note that the presence or absence of the tuple here has no bearing on the thread safety of this code. A `double` is no more thread-safe than a `tuple<double, double, double>`.